# Fastest way to do local IPC between a Unity process and another C# process

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ipc

I want to deliver a huge amount of data around 30 times each second from a C# application to my Unity Application. Since mapped memory and pipes aren't supported in Unity i thought about a tcp socket. Would this be fast enough if the communication is in the scope of one machine only?

Comment: What do you mean by "huge" amount? You can simply write a simple test program and measure the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

---

Possibly as of 2017, Unity also supports [Managed plug-ins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html).

---

Unity3D supports c++ too.

> Native plugins are platform-specific native code libraries. They can access features like **OS calls** and third-party code libraries that would **otherwise not be available to Unity**. However, these libraries are not accessible to Unity’s tools in the way that managed libraries are. For example, if you forget to add a managed plugin file to the project, you will get standard compiler error messages. If you do the same with a native plugin, you will only see an error report when you try to run the project.  [More...](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html)

...and:

> Unity has **extensive support for native Plugins**, which are libraries of native code written in **C, C++**, Objective-C, etc. Plugins allow your game code (written in Javascript or C#) to call functions from these libraries. This feature allows Unity to integrate with middleware libraries or existing C/C++ game code.  [More...](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html).

With c++ code you are free to do anything you want including writing a native name pipe server through which your c# app could send data to.

Local named pipes are incredibly fast because they run in Kernel mode and don't go through the network layer unlike TCP which does.

I would recommend named pipes over TCP if comms is for local machine only.

### Alternatives

Alternatives to named pipes are:

- COM
- DDE
- File mapping (including shared memory, thanks Ben!)
- Mailslots

[Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#base.using_a_mailslot_for_ipc)

Comment: C++ also supports shared memory, which is potentially faster yet (and mentioned in the question).  Native plugins would be a good way to get there, but it's unclear whether security settings would preclude their use.

Comment: @BenVoigt Agreed.  Included

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: Are you sure Unity supports named pipes? As far as i can remeber mono does not have implementations for named pipes.

Comment: @BooNonMooN you would need to do it natively

Comment: So i would have to write it as a native plugin and then use it inside unity?

Comment: @BooNonMooN Unity plugins are pre-compiled so you dont make them in Unity.  You would create a plug-in (native or managed) externally in Visual Studio and compile to a .DLL and **copy** the result to the **Assets\Plugins** folder.   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html.  I'm not aware of native plugin limits but managed plugins must be targeting .NET Standard 2.1 or earlier or .NET Framework 2 to .NET Framework 4.x